# How to view files added through Google service account?

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to create .NET console app to upload/download files to a user's Google drive.

I tried it using service account authorization. But I am not able to view the uploaded files using web UI. I am able view the list of files uploaded using my console APP. But I would like to know whether User Google Drive and files uploaded using my APP are located in different location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Drive access for Service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382342/google-drive-access-for-service-account)

Comment: AFAIK, service account doesn't have UI and files created using service account can only be accessed using your app. One workaround is that you share a directory of the service account's Google Drive to your own to have access to the files being uploaded. Also this directory should be present as a `parentID` when uploading a file using service account.