# List Google Drive files on website from GSuite users

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an organization with GSuite with various users. The organization is connected to a Google app, Google Drive API is enabled, and I have an API Key. I'm trying to list files in a particular folder on various users' Google Drives. For example, I want to list all the pdfs in a folder called "annual reports" under one email, and the Google Docs under another's, with clickable urls to everything. The folders are set to public (anyone on the web can view them), but I cannot figure out how to to do this with php on a public facing website. Basically, I want to be able to go to example.com and see a list of links to each pdf, and a list of links to each Google doc so that the public can view/download things from the organization.

Comment: What is the specific problem/issue you're facing to achieve your goal?

Comment: If the problem is how to obtain the files information, you can create a service account and share the files with it like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382342/google-drive-access-for-service-account)